# Can I use F-test to compare two linear models (not nested)

Tags: linear-model, f-test, inference

I have two models of the following form

```
lmod1 <- lm(response ~ predictor1 + log(predictor2))

lmod2 <- lm(response ~ predictor1 + predictor2)
```

The question is, can I use an F-test to compare these two models? Which model provides a better fit to the data? The question is from the Faraway's Linear Models with R, by the way.

I will add the R code I used and the results, so its easier to discuss something specific.

NOTE: I am told that Acetic and H2S are, in the data, in the log form, so in the second model I eliminate the log by doing $10^{predictor}$.

I understand more or less what the F-statistic and F-test means, but I fail to see the nuance of being able to use it or not for certain comparisons. Regarding the second part of the question (what is the better fit), I would say that it is the first model, due to having a higher $R^{2}$.

I have read something related to using anova and F-test for nested models, which this is not (I think).

```
data("cheddar", package="faraway")
lmod <- lm(taste ~ Acetic + H2S + Lactic, cheddar)
lms <- summary(lmod)
lms


## This is the first model (with log in H2S and Acetic)
## Call:
## lm(formula = taste ~ Acetic + H2S + Lactic, data = cheddar)
## 
## Residuals:
##     Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
## -17.390  -6.612  -1.009   4.908  25.449 
## 
## Coefficients:
##             Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
## (Intercept) -28.8768    19.7354  -1.463  0.15540   
## Acetic        0.3277     4.4598   0.073  0.94198   
## H2S           3.9118     1.2484   3.133  0.00425 **
## Lactic       19.6705     8.6291   2.280  0.03108 * 
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## Residual standard error: 10.13 on 26 degrees of freedom
## Multiple R-squared:  0.6518, Adjusted R-squared:  0.6116 
## F-statistic: 16.22 on 3 and 26 DF,  p-value: 3.81e-06


data("cheddar", package="faraway")
cheddar_org <- cheddar
cheddar_org$Acetic <- 10^cheddar_org$Acetic
cheddar_org$H2S <- 10^cheddar_org$H2S

lmod_org <- lm(taste ~ Acetic + H2S + Lactic, cheddar_org)
lm_org_s <- summary(lmod_org)
lm_org_s

## 
## Call:
## lm(formula = taste ~ Acetic + H2S + Lactic, data = cheddar_org)
## 
## Residuals:
##      Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max 
## -17.2569  -8.3010  -0.7964   7.7366  26.2558 
## 
## Coefficients:
##               Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
## (Intercept) -2.032e+01  1.185e+01  -1.715   0.0982 . 
## Acetic       3.554e-06  3.070e-06   1.158   0.2575   
## H2S          1.103e-09  8.076e-10   1.366   0.1838   
## Lactic       2.890e+01  8.828e+00   3.274   0.0030 **
## ---
## Signif. codes:  0 '***' 0.001 '**' 0.01 '*' 0.05 '.' 0.1 ' ' 1
## 
## Residual standard error: 11.57 on 26 degrees of freedom
## Multiple R-squared:  0.546,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.4936 
## F-statistic: 10.42 on 3 and 26 DF,  p-value: 0.0001108
```

Comment: See e.g. https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/251827/86652 ("Why is F-test not possible for comparing non-nested models").

Answer (score 0):

consider R-square and adjusted R square value for both the models, higher the value better the model. However one should not just rely on these only , other assumptions of regression such as auto correlation and many more has to be considered.

Comment: Thank you very much for response! However, I need to discuss whether I can use a F-test to compare these two models (this is the main question). I understand that a higher R^{2} the better the fit to the data

Comment: (Sorry I can't seem to edit the previous comment and pressed enter by accident)

Comment: (Sorry again, when I try to enter a new line the comment is added). My points was that I understand that the better R^{2} the better fit, but does this also imply a _better_ model? If I add a random predictor, the R^{2} will probably rise, but this does not mean the model is better.